If A,B,C are three matrices of order $2$ , such that $|A+B|−|C|=−10 , |B+C|−|A|=25 , |C+A|−|B|=15$ then value of $|A+B+C|$ is equal to

If $A, B, C$ are three matrices of order $2$, such that $|A+B|-|C|=-10$, $|B+C|-|A|=25$, $|C+A|-|B|=15$ then value of $|A+B+C|$ is equal to ($|A|$ denotes the determinant of matrix $A$)

My Approach: Though I don't know how to approach this problem. But I assumed $3$ matrices  $A,B,C$ of order and try to solve the equation but as there are $12$ variable so it is cumbersome to solve this problem using my method.
Then I saw order of matrices is $2$ so I try to recall the formula when order is $2$ as in Meaning of the identity $\det(A+B)+\text{tr}(AB) = \det(A)+\det(B) + \text{tr}(A)\text{tr}(B)$ (in dimension $2$) but here I am getting trace of $A$ and $B$ involved.
So, Can anyone please guide me to solve this problem?

The answer is $-10+25+15$. Just use the formula you have mentioned.

@Thanks, I got It.
